# How to prioritize custom css over the default Angular-material css

Tags: angularjs, css, angular-material

By default, the search label is padded to left.. i.e., `padding-left: 3px` is assigned by `Angular-material.min.css`

[image]

When I pad it to right by customizing the same in my `custom.less` file, it's not taken high priority over the default css from `Angular-material.min.css`

[image]

Comment: In which order are the CSS files being loaded? Load yours last, and it'll overwrite it, unless there's some nasty `!important` stuff going on.

Comment: !important helped me :)

Comment: @CalebAnthony I've placed the css in the bottom of the .less file, it didn't work

Comment: It's the order in which you load the **files**. For example, in your HTML, you want to load the `angular.css` first, then underneath that, have a separate line that loads your `custom.less`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load your CSS in the proper order.

**HTML**

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Angular-material.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">
</head>
```

This is because the **C** in **CSS** stands for **Cascading**. This means that rules that are seen later on overwrite rules that were seen previously.

Comment: it worked :) actually both the solutions worked... and your solution is apt for this question

Comment: You should always opt for this solution. Using `!important` is considered bad practice.

Comment: [`!important rules`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) are meant to be used in _user_ style sheets; when the _end-user_ needs to override\[1] the page author's styles. You, as the page author, _should not_ use `!important`. (\[1] "[to have more importance or influence than](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/override)")

Comment: I have same issue, but this solution is not working. style in first file is taking precedence. !important rules is working but I had to apply that to all styles in my custom css file. any other solution to specify file priority while adding file?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, see bellow for solution.
on you angular.json file, under your styles, make sure you use your custom style file as the last one

```
"styles": 
  [
     "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
     "src/custom-theme.scss"
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `!important` to your css style property:

```
padding-left: 29px !important;
```

Comment: It's never good practice in CSS to use `!important`. This becomes a bear to maintain once you get enough of these mixed around the CSS.

Comment: fast and dirty solution, sure it will be better check the order of loaded css files, and put yours custom as the last one

Comment: This answer also helps in prioritization :)

Comment: @PrashanthSams using `!important` in your stylesheet is _always_ the wrong thing to do.